# how do I code a simple Random Fact Generator

Tags: java, random

I'm doing a little side project which involves making a simple random facts generator - it will be just clicking a button, and a new fact would appear,randomly from a list of facts - kinda like [WhatTheHeckHasObamaDoneSoFar?](http://whattheheckhasobamadonesofar.com/)

So I'm still very new to Java, but this is very simple so I should be able to do it with a little help!

I'm not sure to begin - I've checked many random number generators/name generators and they are somewhat different. Should I use an Array with facts? How do I write the code for a random presentation of a fact from the Array? I'm not even quite sure about Arrays,are they different files or parts of the code on the main .java file?

Any help would be appreciated! 
If someone could give me the code for a random fact generator that I could re-tweak to my own facts,that'd be super easy for me?

Comment: I understand your source is an apt example, but there are many sites out there which display randomized facts. I strongly suggest keeping political links out of your posts.

Comment: I'm so sorry - I couldn't think of another example at the moment.
And I've tried tweaking random number generators but I get stuck when I get stuck actually getting the facts displayed

Answer (score 2):

Collect your facts (`String` instances) into a list and maintain it (add, remove, update entries as desired).

```
List<String> facts = new ArrayList<String>();
facts.add("I'm a fact myself!");
...
```

Then generate a random integer which will be used for selecting the fact via its index, i.e. random integer will be the index that you will use.

```
Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(100); // Assuming your list contains 100 elements.

String randomFact = facts.get(index); // yepp your random choice is ready.
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This is very helpful,so basically

class FactsGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> facts = new ArrayList<String>();
facts.add("Thank you again");
...

^so this adds all those facts to the facts list - I get that part.

Is this to be saved in a separate file?
and in another txt file - the random integer - doesn't it require a 
System.out.println( fact) to display the fact?

Thank you so much again,for taking the time

Comment: @user1971982 please read and learn about basic java classes and programs, e.g. how to write a program with main method. I have given enough hint for the answer of your question above.

Comment: okay I can figure the rest out on my own,no worries! thanks!